# Manually copy .ISO to bootable USB (without Bootcamp)

Tags: usb, disk-utility

I want to create a bootable Windows USB from my Macbook manually as an alternative to Bootcamp.

1. I've downloaded the Windows 10 ISO file.
2. Formatted an 8GB USB with MS-DOS(FAT) with a Master Boot Record Scheme within Disk Utility.
3. **Question: Can I now finally mount the .ISO and copy it's contents to the USB?**

Please don't reference to Bootcamp in your answers.

Comment: Can I assume this is to install Windows on a 2012 for newer Mac?

Comment: Yes it's a 2015 MacBook Pro

Comment: Indeed you were right - these commands were exactly what I wanted! Cheers @DavidAnderson